# Can Interail passes be used on the Mulhouse tram train?

Tags: public-transport, france, interrail

Im looking at potentially visiting the cite du train in Mulhouse as part of an Interail trip across Europe, as such I'h have a global Interail pass. Looking at the [map](http://www.solea.info/mediadb/solea-plan-ligne-arret-accessible-pmr.pdf) I understand I need to get the tram train from the main station to the Musees stop. I was trying to work out if the Interail pass would be valid for these services, [The Interail.eu](http://www.interrail.eu/en/trains-europe/trains-country/trains-france) site and their app indicates that the passes are valid on SNCF services, but Im still unsure weather or not the tram train is an SNCF service. The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mulhouse_tramway) article on the tram train indicates that 75% of the drivers are from SNCF. So does anyone know if I can use an Interail pass on the Mulhouse tram train or will I need to buy a separate ticket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tram train is part of the [SNCF Ter Alsace](https://www.ter.sncf.com/alsace/gares/87182568/Thann/prochains-departs) it says "DÉPARTS SNCF" and the other says "DÉPARTS CAR, MÉTRO,…" and the TRAM-TRAIN is under "DÉPARTS SNCF". So it qualifies for [Interrail](https://en.voyages-sncf.com/en/pass/seat-reservation).

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that on the website you have provided if a stop severed by trams (Example: Mulhouse Central https://www.ter.sncf.com/alsace/gares/87533620/Mulhouse-Gare-Centrale/prochains-departs) then Trams also appear under the "SNCF Ter Alsace" section, can you confirm that this means Interrail tickets are valid across the whole of the Mulhouse tram network?

Comment: This doesn't follow automatically. For example Interrail is not valid in the Paris suburban network, even though that is run by SNCF. It may well be that Interrail is only valid on the part of the line that runs on historical SNCF tracks, or that it isn't valid at all. Whether it's valid or not, there's a chance that local ticket inspectors wouldn't know; you may be lucky and they'll wave you through because they aren't sure, or you may be unlucky and get a fine even though it turns out to be valid. So it would be best to find an official reference @skifans